# is there a container type object in three.js to transform a group of children?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

is there a container or node object in three.js in which multiple meshes can be added as child so that they can be transformed together?

(an invisible container that allows to perform transformations on all child objects as in a group?)

thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_hierarchy.html).

```
var group = new THREE.Group();

for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;

    mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * 360 * ( Math.PI / 180 );
    mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * 360 * ( Math.PI / 180 );

    group.add( mesh );

}

scene.add( group );
```

r69+

Comment: kinda thought Object3D was some sort of abstract base class, didn't think of using it as a container. works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Has THREE.Group become obsolete?

Comment: @mrdoob Is it `THREE.Group` or `THREE.Object3D`? Why do I not find `Group` in the docs?

Comment: @binki I have looked at the code of Group and in fact it is (almost) just another name for Object3D. There is no new method or attribute, just a type 'group'

Comment: Maybe you should check your THREE version...
It's three.js or three.min.js?

Comment: @mrdoob Can we please get an answer to binki's question? `@mrdoob Is it THREE.Group or THREE.Object3D? Why do I not find Group in the docs?`

Comment: @MatthewCliatt You can use either, but THREE.Group will be faster. THREE.Group is subclass of Object3D that is optimized as a container. The renderer will not look for materials and other properties during the rendering cycle.  [See this thread.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8711)  The documentation on THREE.Group is missing