# How to compose two cubes in one object?

Tags: three.js

I need to manage position of group of objects as one item.

I have:

```
tankMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
tankMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(tankMesh1);
scene.add(tankMesh2);

tankMesh2.position = tankMesh2.position + offset * cos ( angle )
```

I need:

```
tankMeshBig = new THREE.Mesh(tankMesh1 , tankMesh2 );
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ksRyQ/2287/

Comment: possible duplicate of [three.js - mesh group example? (THREE.Object3D() advanced)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985805/three-js-mesh-group-example-three-object3d-advanced)

Comment: See `THREE.GeometryUtils.merge()` in [docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/GeometryUtils).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a new `THREE.Object3D()`:

js:

```
var group=new THREE.Object3D();

tankMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
group.add(tankMesh1);

geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(3, 2, 5);
tankMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
tankMesh2.position.y = 3;
group.add(tankMesh2);

group.rotation.y = 3.141/3;

scene.add(group);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zYLSC/

Comment: If you are going to take this approach, then in your fiddle, you should be translating/rotating the group, not the meshes themselves.